# Why poke straw in center of sealed Boba cup? Why hit center of wooden barrel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, torque, surface-tension

So I'm curious to know why, so very naturally, I have been poking my thick straw at the center of the seal of Boba cup. Why not the side, nearer to the brim where the plastic is not so stretchy? Intuitively, the center appears to be where most force from me will be efficiently translated (in other cases too; be it punching to open a wooden barrel from its top)

Some guesses I've had in making sense of my actions:
(assuming uniform thickness of the plastic seal)

- I had applied my intuition with levers. The brim of the cup (where plastic seal is glued to) is hereby the "pivot" of this lever. So the further from the brim, or nearer to the center, the more translated(?) my force becomes when breaking open the seal with straw.
- It is simply more stable, and not anything to do with strength of force. By poking in the center, my cup is less likely to flip.

It's not the exact phenomena (of my actions) that I am so interested in, but more an explanation as to why we poke/punch/hit sealed things at the center, assuming uniform thickness of the seal.

Please excuse me for this convoluted and possibly unscientific phrasing. My formal physics education ended in middle school and I haven't done anything much since. This question might nudge me to consider study physics properly though!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The straw has a (surprising) amount of compressive axial strength, but very little strength away from the axis.  In other words, it will bend easily if there are sideways forces.  If you place it under moderate compression it is okay, but adding a small sideways force to it at the same time will cause it to buckle.

You may not have much information about the lid of the cup, but you can assume that in the center, the response to poking will at least be roughly symmetrical.  If the material were to stretch significantly before failing, it will stretch downward.

If you were to poke off-center, then the stretching might be toward or away from the nearby edge.  If that were to happen unexpectedly, the straw has a greater chance of buckling before the material yields.

Comment: When using a metallic straw, will it not still be advantageous to poke it at the center of the seal film?